# Python Telegram Bot check if all updates processed

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) for one simple bot. Is there any way to make sure all updates that i've got previously are processed before requesting new ones?

Comment: Is it Bot API issue? You can do it by many ways, with setting flag for example

Comment: It's not an issue actually, i can always set a flag or something like that, i was  just looking for built-in feature for doing such thing. I couldn't find it in docs, maybe i missed something.